# Get the ISO 8601 Week of the Year in FreeMarker based on a date

Tags: date, freemarker, week-number

I need to get the current week of the year based on a string date.
E.g. `07.03.2023` → `Week 10 of 2023`.

In the [docs](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html#ref_builtin_date_datetype) I found many helpers, but none for the week of the year.

```
<#assign aDate = theDate?date>
<!-- All kind of day of the week, month, year etc, -->
${aDate?string["EEE, MMM d, ''yy"]}
<!-- How to get the week of the year? -->
```

How could I get the week of the year of a date using just the FreeMarker template?

Comment: What type of week number? ISO? US?

Comment: Any is OK. ISO preferred.

Comment: The definition of week-in-year vary by culture. You really need to specify which definition you want. [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date) is but one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeMarker uses the [Java simple date format patterns](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) to format dates. You can use the `w` pattern to get the "week in year". So you can simply do:

```
Current week number: ${.now?string['w']}
```

As Basil pointed out, you want to make sure you are using the right locale. There are several ways to [set the locale in FreeMarker](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/pgui_config_settings.html).

Comment: **Beware:** I suspect that "Week in year" code `w` in the obsolete `SimpleDateFormat` will vary in its results by the JVM’s current default `Locale`. Definition of week-in-year vary by culture. This seems like an unreliable and troublesome approach.